# Visual C++ message box different behavior if click OK or hit enter

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, messagebox

In visual c++, I am using a message box to warn the user about invalid entry in a dialog. When the entry is invalid and the user clocks OK in the dialog, a message box pops up which the user acknowledges by clicking OK and the original dialog is still available for the user to correct his entry.

My problem is that I see different behavior when the user hits enter on the keyboard vs clicking on the OK button in the dialog. When the user hits enter instead of clicking OK in the original dialog, the message still pops up but then everything goes away after the message is acknowledged (the dialog does not persist under it like with clicking OK).

The message box is based on WinUser.h method MessageBoxA. Any suggestions why this is or how to work around it?

Comment: The message box closes on the key-down message and the focus goes back to the dialog.  Whatever control on that dialog has the focus, your OK button in this case, will see the key-up message.  It should ignore that message of course, sounds like it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the CANCEL option is the DEFAULT - Enter key will simulate the click of the DEFAULT Button, i.e the one with the dashed frame

Comment: I will look into the DEFAULT option but it seems like enter defaults to OK my case because I can tell the process commences and does not cancel

Comment: DEFPUSHBUTTON is set to OK button in the original dialog. But clicking it has a "shallower" response than hitting enter somehow

Comment: I would inspect the code associated with the OK button of the original form. Obviously it includes logic to validate the entry and then EITHER close the dialog, OR Popup the Secondary Dialog to warn the user. Thus, you need to check the code following the call to the secondary dialog. At that point is supposes to UNCONDITIONALLY return focus to the original dialog offensive entry field. In your case, that code somehow continues to CLOSE the Dialog.